# How to open react-dropzone input file dialog programatically?

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I am using `noClick` and would like to have a button open the file dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found how in the [docs](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/tree/master/examples/file-dialog).

> You can programmatically invoke the default OS file prompt; just use the open method returned by the hook.

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone';

function Dropzone(props) {
  const {getRootProps, getInputProps, open, acceptedFiles} = useDropzone({
    // Disable click and keydown behavior
    noClick: true,
    noKeyboard: true
  });

  const files = acceptedFiles.map(file => (
    <li key={file.path}>
      {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div {...getRootProps({className: 'dropzone'})}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here</p>
        <button type="button" onClick={open}>
          Open File Dialog
        </button>
      </div>
      <aside>
        <h4>Files</h4>
        <ul>{files}</ul>
      </aside>
    </div>
  );
}

<Dropzone />
```